# How to fix "Error: ';' expected" or "Error: ')' expected" and errors in the boolean

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to create a validation for the ExpenseName and ExpenseCost Edittext so that if there is no user input it will alert the user to input some data and the "text" in the boolean also has an error on it cause it is colour red. I copied the code from another .java so that I'm pretty sure it's working just fine

```
package com.example.back4app.userregistrationexample.Classes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.back4app.userregistrationexample.R;

public class ExpenseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText ExpenseName;
private EditText ExpenseCost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense);

    ExpenseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_expensename);
    ExpenseCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_expensecost);

    final Button btn_addexpense = findViewById(R.id.btn_addexpense);
        btn_addexpense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()); {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Validating the log in data
                boolean validationError = false;

                StringBuilder validationErrorMessage = new StringBuilder("Please, insert ");
                if (isEmpty(ExpenseCost)) {
                    validationError = true;
                    validationErrorMessage.append("the cost of the expense");
                }
                if (isEmpty(ExpenseName)) {
                    if (validationError) {
                        validationErrorMessage.append(" and ");
                    }
                    validationError = true;
                    validationErrorMessage.append("the name of the expense");
                }
            }
        }

    private boolean isEmpty(EditText text) {
        if (text.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I tried putting '(' and ')' outside the "text" but it is still colour red, and I also tried changing the "isEmpty" to any other name cause maybe it's reading on the other .java but still the same thing happen. Also, I tried to Rebuild Project and Clean Project but nothing worked, Also I tried to Invalidate Caches / Restart cause I have read someone said it is not uncommon for android to have bugs like this. Is there a problem with my code?

EDIT:

Okay. So I closed the OnClickListener but now more "error: ';' expected" appeared and "OnClickListener' is abstract; cannot be instantiated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not close `onCreate` or `setOnClickListener` in the code you posted.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense);

    ExpenseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_expensename);
    ExpenseCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_expensecost);

    final Button btn_addexpense = findViewById(R.id.btn_addexpense);
    btn_addexpense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                //Validating the log in data
                boolean validationError = false;

               StringBuilder validationErrorMessage = new StringBuilder("Please, insert ");
                if (isEmpty(ExpenseCost)) {
                    validationError = true;
                    validationErrorMessage.append("the cost of the expense");
                }
                if (isEmpty(ExpenseName)) {
                    if (validationError) {
                        validationErrorMessage.append(" and ");
                    }
                    validationError = true;
                    validationErrorMessage.append("the name of the expense");
                }
        }
    }); // here
}

private boolean isEmpty(EditText text) {
    if (text.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is because your `.setOnClickListener` is not closed.

```
  final Button btn_addexpense = findViewById(R.id.btn_addexpense);
    btn_addexpense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Validating the log in data
            boolean validationError = false;

            StringBuilder validationErrorMessage = new StringBuilder("Please, insert ");
            if (isEmpty(ExpenseCost)) {
                validationError = true;
                validationErrorMessage.append("the cost of the expense");
            }
            if (isEmpty(ExpenseName)) {
                if (validationError) {
                    validationErrorMessage.append(" and ");
                }
                validationError = true;
                validationErrorMessage.append("the name of the expense");
            }
        }
    });    //add a parentheses and semicolon to close the onClickListener
```